# SPARQL query not working - SNOMED-CT ontology

Tags: sparql, ontology, snomed-ct

I'm trying to execute a very simple SPARQL query to retrieve information about a specific disease using https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/SNOMEDCT/?p=classes&conceptid=root (in Java) based on a name passed in the query string, and I don't understand why it's not working. Here are the relevant code:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/SNOMEDCT>
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/globals>
WHERE
{
    ?x rdfs:label ?label .
    FILTER (CONTAINS ( UCASE(str(?label)), "MELANOMA") )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only occurrence of `rdfs:label` in SNOMED-CT on BioPortal is `snomed-term: rdfs:label "SNOMEDCT"`. BioPortal [uses](https://www.bioontology.org/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_BioPortal#BioPortal_Preferred_Label) `skos:prefLabel` (which is a [subproperty](https://www.w3.org/2009/08/skos-reference/skos.html#prefLabel) of `rdfs:label`) instead.

Try this query:

```sql
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX snomed-term: <http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/SNOMEDCT/>

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/SNOMEDCT>
FROM <http://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/globals>
WHERE {
    ?x skos:prefLabel ?label .
    FILTER (CONTAINS ( UCASE(str(?label)), "MELANOMA") )
}
```

There should be 10 results.

If you need to restrict results to *diseases*, probably you'd have to add `?x rdfs:subClassOf+ snomed-term:64572001` to your query.   But unfortunately, it seems that the BioPortal SPARQL endpoint doesn't support SPARQL 1.1 property paths.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it does not return all the results? For example, if I change `FILTER (CONTAINS ( UCASE(str(?label)), "MELANOMA") )` to `FILTER ( STR(?prefLabel)="Edema")` I'm not getting any results, even though, on a manual search on ontology there are 3 results.

Comment: @ela, I suppose, you mean `:267038008`, `:79654002` and `:423666004`. Well, BioPortal [say](https://www.bioontology.org/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_BioPortal#Partial_or_Incomplete_Results): "***Partial or Incomplete Results**. Sparql.bioontology.org uses 4store's soft-limit internal mechanism to limit resources for expensive queries.*" etc. `FILTER (?label = "Edema"@en)` works better. Or use your own local endpoint.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate all the help you have given me with my bugs.